# How does Apache 2.4 authorization container RequireAll evaluate conditions?

Tags: apache2.4, mod-authz-host

The [documentation of the `RequireAll` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireall)  says :

> `<RequireAll>` and `</RequireAll>` are used to enclose a group of authorization directives of which **none must fail** and **at least one must succeed** in order for the  directive to succeed.

This suggests that authorization directives have a "not failed" status which is not "success" either (or I am missing something, which is my point ;-)

[This bug report (point 1)](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65145) refers to tri-state authorization status (success / failure / neutral) but I couldn't find anything else about this, even in the official documentation.

Last point (maybe not directly related to this 3-state question but participating to my misunderstanding) : [the "Access control by host" documentation page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html#host) states

> You can insert `not` to negate a particular requirement. Note, that since a `not` is a negation of a value, it cannot be used by itself to allow or deny a request, as `not true` does not constitute `false`.
>
> Thus, to deny a visit using a negation, the block must have one element that evaluates as `true` or `false`. For example, if you have someone (with IP 10.252.46.165) spamming your message board, and you want to keep them out, you could do the following:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not ip 10.252.46.165
</RequireAll>
```

To me, `Require ip 10.252.46.165` would be :

- for the owner of that IP : `true`
- for anybody else : `false`

and `Require not ip 10.252.46.165` :

- for the owner of that IP : `false`
- for anybody else : `true`

What's the point of emphasizing that "`not true` isn't `false`" ?
Can you, please, give some use cases with explanations ?